# Does Bing execute Javascript when crawling and indexing web pages (like Google)?

Tags: javascript, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, bing

Some content on some web pages is only displayed with Javascript when a button is clicked (for example). We know that Google executes Javascript and is (very likely) to find this content, but what about Bing? Do Bing web crawlers execute Javascript too?

Comment: Personally, I don't see much evidence that Bingbot is processing JavaScript.

Comment: I did a search and I cannot find anything... so assume the worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.rimmkaufman.com/blog/googlebot-crawling-javascript-site-ready/03062014/) we are still waiting to see what Bing will do, so I would assume (I know) not.

Here is an excerpt regarding Bing:

> What Can We Expect?
>
> Google’s disregard for JavaScript in the past has also been used by
>   many websites to their advantage. It will be important to understand
>   the repercussions of Google being able to index all of the content and
>   assets on your pages, as it will be able to see your pages as a user
>   can now.
>
> This announcement creates more questions than it answers, especially
>   considering the versatility and expanding capabilities of JavaScript.
>   We don’t truly know what Google’s goals are for this update, but RKG
>   is formulating testing to better understand the ramifications.
>
> A few scenarios to think about:
>
> Is your site is hiding duplicate content behind JavaScript, perhaps by
>   a review aggregator, will Googlebot now crawl all of that duplicate
>   content?
>
> Will all JavaScript links in  tags or JavaScript jump menus from
>   forms suddenly count as links?
>
> How will faceted navigation within JavaScript be interpreted?
>
> Will the execution of JavaScript by Googlebot be in small, incremental
>   waves or  will this new capability be a fire-hose that is simply
>   turned on?
>
> **How will Bing respond?**
>
> Do the crawlers that you use internally for your own site analysis
>   have the ability to execute JavaScript?  Will they no longer be able
>   to mimic Googlebot?

Answer (score 3):

As of 2018, [the Bing Team clarified](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/october-2018/bingbot-Series-JavaScript,-Dynamic-Rendering,-and-Cloaking-Oh-My) that **bingbot is generally able to render JavaScript**. They do recommend detecting the bingbot user agent and prerendering the content on the server side and outputting static HTML in order to "increase the predictability of crawling and indexing by Bing".

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it and Bing found page with all text build purely by JavaScript. Google also finds it of course.

Comment: Can you provide an example that you tested?

Comment: I hope it will not be taken as advertisment, search for:
"you will deliver an exceptional customer experience on-time"

Comment: According to our logs it seems like Bing Bot started running javascripts